# Code reuse with different event methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, reusability

I have two similar pieces of code in two different functions of my project
and I want to get rid of the repeating code. How can I do that?

#### 1:

```
getArray("my-hand").forEach(function(elem){
    $(elem).mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css({'top': '1em'});
    });
    $(elem).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css({'top': '0em'});
    });
    $(elem).click(function(){   
        var cardNode = $(this).get(0);
        //some jquery animation
        play(cardNode,time);
    });
})
```

and the second piece

#### 2:

```
getArray("my-hand").forEach(function(elem){
    $(elem).mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css({'top': '1em'});
    });
    $(elem).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css({'top': '0em'});
    });
    $(elem).click(function(){   
        var cardNode = $(this).get(0);
        //a function with another jquery animation
        validateCardAndAddForCollection(checkNumber,cardNode,time);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to put it in a function, and pass as an argument to that function a callback that will execute the desired code:

```
function handleCards (cb) {
    getArray("my-hand").forEach(function(elem){
        $(elem).mouseover(function(){
            $(this).css({'top': '1em'});
        });
        $(elem).mouseout(function(){
            $(this).css({'top': '0em'});
        });
        $(elem).click(function(){   
            var cardNode = $(this).get(0);
            //some jquery animation

            cb(cardNode);
        });
    });
}

handleCards(function (cardNode) {
    play(cardNode, time);
});

handleCards(function (cardNode) {
    validateCardAndAddForCollection(checkNumber,cardNode,time);
});
```

Comment: perhaps `getCardNode` is a misleading name, as it doesn't really return anything, and it's primary purpose is essentially bootstrapping events for particular elements.

Comment: @shennan You're right; I hadn't noticed this was in a loop. Overall, the design of the code could be greatly improved.

Comment: I perhaps forgot to tell that two pieces of code are embedded in two
different functions that look like

var func1 = function(time){
   // bunch of code
   //repeating piece of code
}

var func2 = function(checkNumber, time){
   // another bunch of code
   //repeating piece of code
}

Comment: @ԱրաՄարտիրոսյան This can still absolutely work -- just call `handleCards()` inside each of those functions.

Comment: @Purag thank you. You where right it worked. I voted for your answer but It did not change since i have no reputation so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the main re-usable logic is the setting up of the events. In that case, I would use a `setupHandEvents` method to do all of the boring stuff, but pass it a different method to represent it's `click` handler.

```
function setupHandEvents (hand, handler){

    getArray(hand).forEach(function (elem) {
        $(elem).mouseover(function () {
            $(this).css({'top': '1em'});
        });
        $(elem).mouseout(function () {
            $(this).css({'top': '0em'});
        });
        $(elem).click(function (){   
            handler($(this).get(0));
        });
    });
}

setupHandEvents('my-hand', function (cardNode) {

    play(cardNode, time);

});

setupHandEvents('my-hand', function (cardNode) {

    validateCardAndAddForCollection(checkNumber, cardNode, time);

});
```

***Update***

You've commented on the other answer that you have these re-used pieces of code wrapped up inside another function (one that delivers variables `checkNumber` and `time` from elsewhere. Here is how you would use my `setupHandEvents` method with the code you posted in that comment:

```
var func1 = function(time){

    setupHandEvents('my-hand', function (cardNode) {
        play(cardNode, time);
    });
}

var func2 = function(checkNumber, time){

    setupHandEvents('my-hand', function (cardNode) {
        validateCardAndAddForCollection(checkNumber, cardNode, time);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this did not work for me. The hand cards do not even move when I hover on the hand cards. I would like to invite your attention on the checkNumber and time parameters which are passed externally as arguments to the functions  containing these two pieces of code

Comment: @ԱրաՄարտիրոսյան can you please update your code with some more context to those functions. If you do this now I can advise you on how to use what I have given you, or change it if it needs changing.

Comment: @ԱրաՄարտիրոսյան please mark as correct if the answer solved your problem.